# Getting Database Data Without Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I have created an SQLite database in Android Studio and would like to view the data in a table form, for which I have installed the DB Browser for SQLite. Unfortunately, I am not able to open up Android Device Monitor to access the data file. I have tried running Android Studio as an admin, but that doesn't work either. It is my understanding that most components of the Android Device Monitor are deprecated, but I am not able to find out what else to use.

Comment: Use the Device File Explorer in Android Studio 3.0+.

Answer (score 0):

you can use stetho, using this you can view your DB from chrome

refer this links

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/debugging-android-apps-with-facebooks-stetho--cms-24205

https://github.com/facebook/stetho